# WebStorm PhpStorm: how to skip specific extensions from indexing

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

WebStorm / PhpStorm IDEs allow the user to mark certain directories as "excluded", so that they will not be indexed and the classes contained will not show up in autocomplete etc... ([see here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207069905-How-to-disable-indexing-for-cetrain-directories-))

Is it possible to mark specific extensions as excluded.  All my components have a pair of files such as:

```
my.component.ts  <-- actual component
my.component.spec.ts <-- for testing only
```

I've seen [this doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/excluding-files-from-project.html) about how to exclude an individual file, but that doesn't scale well. I would like all the `.spec.ts` files to be ignored by the indexer because they pollute a lot of the autocomplete UI and slow down my work.

Comment: 1) You can go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` and associate `*.spec.ts` pattern with `Text` file type. Now all such files will be treated as Plain Text files. NOTE -- it will affect ALL projects. 2) Or you can add that pattern to the `Ignore files and folders` field (same settings screen) -- it will simply exclude/ignore such files completely from the project (will not even show them in the Project View tree -- might be an overkill). Same NOTE: it's an IDE-wide setting so affects ALL projects.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks. On the dialog for the new file type, I don't see an option to treat the file as `Text`.  Am I missing the obvious? https://imagebin.ca/v/3S7aOBGJvpwY

Comment: you don't need a new file type here; just open `Settings | Editor | File Types`. select `Text` type there, and add `*.spec.ts` to the list of registered patterns in the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WebStorm/PhpStorm 2017.2 it will be possible to exclude files by pattern - see  [IDEA-127753](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127753).
Note also that you can use **Ignore files and folders** option to exclude certain files by name ( see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127753#comment=27-868409 )

Comment: Hi lena. Thanks. Excluding by name is not a good solution because I have many files to be excluded.  Ignoring files is not a good one for me either because I want them to show up in the file manager, but not be indexed....actually, on 2nd thought i'll take your advice